# How can I optimize my LinkedList InsertionAtEnd() code?

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
// function inserts the data in front of the list
Node *insertAtBegining(Node *head, int newData) {
   // Your code here

  Node* new_node = new Node(newData);
  new_node = head;
  head = new_node;
  return head;
}


// function appends the data at the end of the list
Node *insertAtEnd(Node *head, int newData)  {
   // Your code here
   Node* new_node = new Node(newData);
   Node* last = head;

   if(head == NULL){
       last = new_node;
       return last;
   }    else    {
       while(last != NULL){
           last = last++;
       }

       last = new_node;
   }
      new_node->next = NULL;

   return last;
}
```

The output I'm getting mentioned below!

Output:

**Your program took more time than expected. Time Limit Exceeded
Expected Time Limit < 0sec
Hint-: Please optimize your code and submit again.**

Comment: `last = last++;` has undefined behaviour *and* is not the proper way to move to the next linked node.

Comment: You have a big problem: In the loop to find the last node of the list, where is `last` pointing when the loop ends? Please try to draw a simple linked list using pen and paper (using boxes for the nodes and arrows for the pointers). Do the operations by erasing and redrawing the arrows as needed.

Comment: You have a runaway loop.  Put printf in your loops to find out where, then how, then fix it.

Comment: As for "optimizations", keep a separate `tail` pointer to always point to the last node in the list?

Comment: Lastly, please don't mix C and C++ tags, unless the code and the problem you ask about really is written in both those languages. Your code is C++ (barely), so please [edit] your question to remove the C language tag.

Comment: Forget about "optimizing" until you have fixed the bugs (that can't possible have worked when you tested it). `insertAtBegining` does the same as only `return head;`, but with an added memory leak. If the loop in  `insertAtEnd` weren't fundamentally broken, that function would do the same as `Node* new_node = new Node(newData); if (head != NULL)  { new_node->next = NULL; } return new_node;`

Comment: `Please optimize your code and submit again` -- That is a misleading message.  Your code is *broken* -- no amount of optimization will fix a broken program.  You need to fix your program.